# Rewriting WordPress theme files redirecting all content to index.php in httpd.conf

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am using WordPress on RHEL6, and have some rewrites so that CSS is hosted at `http://servername/css` rather than `http://servername/wp-content/themes/themename/css/`.

I am moving from an Nginx install to Apache, and own the server. In that case, I don't want to use htaccess for redirects, I just want them in the httpd.conf. If I enable htaccess and put this in there, it all seems to work fine.

In my conversion, I added the / at the beginning of the rule. The current code below works for everything, except real files not handled by the css, js, img, font rules. As in, things that are actually hosted under /assets or other directories. I have a feeling this is due to the REQUEST_FILENAME, and if anything, a slash missing for the next rule - but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/font/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/font/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If I try to access `http://servername/assets/image.png`, I actually am being rewritten to /index.php, from the rewrite log

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /assets/311.jpg
applying pattern '^/index\.php$' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '^/css/(.*)' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '^/js/(.*)' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '^/img/(.*)' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '^/font/(.*)' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '^/plugins/(.*)' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
applying pattern '.' to uri '/assets/311.jpg'
RewriteCond: input='/assets/311.jpg' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/assets/311.jpg' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite '/assets/311.jpg' -> '/index.php'
```

`/assets` is a real folder that has real images. By looking at this log, it would make me think that `!-f` should have said 'yes, this is a file', rather than passing it to index.php afterwards.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your rules only apply to `css`,`js`,`img`,`font` and `plugin`. I don't see no rule for `assets`

Comment: There is none - /assets is a real directory with files. I thought the REQUEST_FILENAME would have considered to be a real file and ignore, versus sending to index.php but not sure whats going on here.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteRule ^/assets/ - [L]` at the top

Comment: It's not just the assets directory though. Its any static file not covered by those css, js, img rules.

Comment: Did the rule I provided work?

Comment: Have not been able to test yet. But how would this solve all static files under other directories?

Comment: Not, but you could add similar rules for those other folders. Something like `RewriteRule ^/wp-content/themes/ - [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and testing, I found this was easily related to the difference in scope between htaccess and httpd.conf, and needing to include `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

If you are using htaccess in /var/www/html/test/, you will only be looking in /test, and therefore something like test/assets/image.jpg would pass, because /assets/image.jpg is valid.

In the case of httpd.conf though, unless you use these rules inside a Directory directive, you are not pathed to the virtual host folder. So in my case, it was looking for /assets/image.jpg off the root of the server.

To get around this, I just had to include `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` before `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`.

My final block in httpd.conf looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/font/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/font/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```